# Can't hover on Submenu

Tags: comments, sub-menu

I'm having trouble with the submenu on my site. When I hover over the main menu item, the submenu shows up as usual. However, when I try to hover over the submenu items to click on them they just disappear. The menu items are all links to different pages of my site. I had a programmer look over my coding and there didn't seem to be an issue with it.
Any ideas? I'm using the Travelify free Wordpress theme.

Comment: If your menu has a bootstrap dropdown like functionality, maybe some element is above your menu and he is losing focus, can you post the link to your site?

Comment: www.myabbydesign.com/firstseder

Comment: do you still have any problem, i see on your site...all looks fine

Comment: So, the submenu is working fine here for me too, you fixed it?

Comment: ya not sure what i did but it started working...thx

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your question, your submenu is on

class,normally your hover style is working on.. so we can use a filter "nav_menu_css_class" on your functions.php file.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

it would be more easy to figure-out the error, if you can share your code and screenshots. Hope this will solve your issue